# Обобщенный список List

Tags: c#, list

Как правильно поступить, у меня есть интерфейс(`ICommon<T>`), есть его несколько реализаций (`HelloInt:ICommon<int>`, `HelloDouble:ICommon<double>`). Теперь я хотел бы создать список `List<ICommon<T>>`. Как это реализовать, и реализуется ли это вообще.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ICommon<T>> com = new List<ICommon<T>>()
        {
            new HelloInt(),
            new HelloDouble()
        };
    }

}

public interface ICommon<T> 
{
    T Hello();
}

public class HelloInt : ICommon<int>
{
    public int Hello()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
public class HelloDouble : ICommon<double>
{
    public double Hello()
    {
        return 2.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите создать список и заполнить его типами `HelloInt` и `HelloDouble` одновременно?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, Да( я понимаю что это не возможно.

Comment: Все типы наследуются от `Object`. В вашем случае `var list = new List<Object> { new HelloInt(), new HelloDouble() };`

Comment: Какую ошибку, простите?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, ошибочка. Ошибку не выдает, добавлять я могу, но не могу вытянуть метод `Hello()`. Мне доступны стандартные методы класса Object.

Comment: [Приведение типов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) `((ICommon<int>) list[0]).Hello()`

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, да всё верно, моя ошибка

Comment: Как вы потом хотите этим пользоваться? Компилятору то нужно будет знать, что отдает ваш Hello. Либо это и дальше будет общий T, либо уже конкретные типы.

Comment: @Monk, Есть конкретные типы) просто нужно все реализации забросить в 1 лист, что бы в зависимости от типа поступившего вытянуть нужный метод и нужной реализации

Comment: Хм, а как пройтись по такой коллекции циклом то?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list = new ArrayList() { new HelloInt(), new HelloDouble() };
```

что мешает сделать так?

Comment: Не получу доступ к методу Hello

Comment: @Valera, как это не получишь?)
   var element = (ICommon<int>)list[0];
   var result = element.Hello();
примерно так

Comment: Ес, так работает)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно при использовании вашего интерфейса указывать не шаблон, а конкретный тип.

Например:

```
public interface ITest<T> where T: class
{
    T TestMethod1();
    T TestMethod2();
}

List<ITest<object>> testObjects = new List<ITest<object>>();
```

Comment: А если у меня несколько реализаций интерфейса с разными типами, int, double?

Comment: Я подправил вопрос. Возможно он не давал полной информации, что я хочу сделать.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<Object> { new HelloInt(), new HelloDouble() };  

Console.WriteLine(((ICommon<int>)list[0]).Hello());
```

либо

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList() { new HelloDouble(), new HelloInt() };

Console.WriteLine(((ICommon<double>)arrayList[0]).Hello());
```